# How to refer 'decider' in the where clause from the following mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, mysql-error-1054

How to refer 'decider' in the where clause from the following mysql query?

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE
         WHEN (cond1) THEN 1
         WHEN (cond2) THEN 2
       END as decider
  FROM t1,
       t2 
 WHERE cond12
   AND decider <> NULL
```

I tried it, and I got a `1054: Unknown column in where clause` error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use a column I have selected later in a query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195704/can-i-use-a-column-i-have-selected-later-in-a-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE
         WHEN (cond1) THEN 1
         WHEN (cond2) THEN 2
         ELSE NULL
       END as decider
  FROM t1,
       t2 
 WHERE cond12
HAVING decider IS NOT NULL
```

1. The earliest MySQL allows you to use column aliases is the `GROUP BY` clause
2. You need to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` (where appropriate) because `NULL` is not a value -- it's a placeholder for the lack of any value, which requires special handling in SQL