# How to get the where clause from IQueryable defined as interface

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, expression-trees

```
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var c = new SampleClass<ClassString>();
        c.ClassStrings.Add(new ClassString{ Name1 = "1", Name2 = "1"});
        c.ClassStrings.Add(new ClassString{ Name1 = "2", Name2 = "2"});

        var result = c.Query<ClassString>().Where(s => s.Name1.Equals("2"));

        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class ClassString
{
    public string Name1 { get; set; }
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
}



public interface ISampleQ
{
    IQueryable<T> Query<T>() where T: class , new();
}
public class SampleClass<X> : ISampleQ
{
    public List<X> ClassStrings { get; private set; }

    public SampleClass()
    {
        ClassStrings = new List<X>();
    }


    public IQueryable<T> Query<T>() where T : class, new()
    {
        //Get the WHERE expression from here.
        return new EnumerableQuery<T>((IEnumerable<T>) ClassStrings);
    }
}
```

I looked into this [solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902721/detect-where-applied-to-iqueryablet'), [solution2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902721/detect-where-applied-to-iqueryablet/7902840#7902840) and [solution3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209383/how-to-refer-decider-in-the-where-clause-from-the-following-mysql-query) seems not applicable to my question. Since the where clause was defined outside and it was interface of the class. How to get the expression inside Query method? since no variable being pass thru.

The purpose, I want the retrieve and injected back into the destination (which is DBContext as IQueryable). Because we have a common interface for us like this ISampleQ.

---

Added new sample codes but same scenario:

```
 internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var oracleDbContext = new OracleDbContext();
        var result = oracleDbContext.Query<Person>().Where(person => person.Name.Equals("username"));

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public interface IGenericQuery
{
    IQueryable<T> Query<T>() where T : class , new();
}

public class OracleDbContext : IGenericQuery
{
    public OracleDbContext()
    {
        //Will hold all oracle operations here. For brevity, only
        //Query are exposed.
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Query<T>() where T : class, new()
    {
        //Get the where predicate here. Since the where was defined outside of the
        //class. I want to retrieve since the IQueryable<T> is generic to both class
        //OracleDbContext and MssqlDbContext. I want to re-inject the where or add 
        //new expression before calling.
        //
        //For eg.
        //oracleDbContext.Query<T>(where clause from here)
        return null;
    }
}

public class MssqlDbContext : IGenericQuery
{
    public MssqlDbContext()
    {
        //Will hold all MSSQL operations here. For brevity, only
        //Query are exposed.
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Query<T>() where T : class, new()
    {
        //Get the where predicate here.
        return null;
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You could implement your `EnumerableQuery<T>` (so the `IQueryable<T>` and `IQueryProvider` interfaces). It is a little complex but doable... but you have given too little details about what you want to obtain... it becomes complex to give a full example.

Comment: The question is very unclear and code seems to be over-complicated for a simple scenario like this. Why not use `var result = c.ClassStrings.Where(s => s.Name1.Equals("2"));` instead?

Comment: @KasparsOzols Yes, but this not what I wanted. I want to get the where predicate inside Query<T> methods before further invoking the call.

Comment: The query method is called before the where method is called, so you are trying to catch it from the wrong end.
What is it exactly that you want to do?

Comment: @MBoros Because the front end application needs only to know the IGenericQuery interface which he called by Query<TEntity>().Where(entity => conditions). It doest care if EF/Nh is sponsoring the query. Can you suggest an interface layout for both ORM compatibility? What abstraction interface suitable for front end that can call an generic query without knowing what ORM are being used.

Comment: Ok, in this case the IQueryable is a good abstraction.
Why do you need to retrieve the Where in the Query method call? To me it seems that all you have to do, is return in the EF version a DbSet<T> (which already implements IQueryable<T>), and in case of NHibernate the appropriate counterpart (session.Query<T>() ?). You can do a default filtering before returning the IQueryable from the interface.
Then all the Where and Select and OrderBy calls will go on top of that in the expression tree, and then its the job of the ORM layer to translate that to sql.
What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Yes, for NH you can call session.Query<T>() (it have an INhQueryProvider) but for EF no direct way since it was implemented from IDSet/DbSet. I tried the ObjectContext, the QueryProvider is not accessible since it is protected internal. I want to expose the interface with Query<T> method to the external consumer (consumer doesn't knew what ORM they connected), they can attached "where" predicate. It's up for the ORM to get all of those predicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is quite complex... Now... the `Queryable.Where()` works this way:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
{
    return source.Provider.CreateQuery<TSource>(Expression.Call(null, ...
```

So the `Queryable.Where` calls the `source.Provider.CreateQuery()` that retuns a new `IQueryable<>`. So if you want to be able to "see" a `Where()` while it is being added (and manipulate it), you must "be" the `IQueryable<>.Provider`, and have your `CreateQuery()`, so you must create a class that implements `IQueryProvider` (and probably a class that implements `IQueryable<T>`).

Another way (much simpler) is to have a simple query "converter": a method that accepts a `IQueryable<>` and returns a manipulated `IQueryable<>`:

```
var result = c.Query<ClassString>().Where(s => s.Name1.Equals("2")).FixMyQuery();
```

As I said, the full route is quite long:

```
namespace Utilities
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public class ProxyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        protected static readonly MethodInfo ProxifySetsMethod = typeof(ProxyDbContext).GetMethod("ProxifySets", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        protected static class ProxyDbContexSetter<TContext> where TContext : ProxyDbContext
        {
            public static readonly Action<TContext> Do = x => { };

            static ProxyDbContexSetter()
            {
                var properties = typeof(TContext).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);

                ParameterExpression context = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TContext), "context");

                FieldInfo manipulatorField = typeof(ProxyDbContext).GetField("Manipulator", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
                Expression manipulator = Expression.Field(context, manipulatorField);

                var sets = new List<Expression>();

                foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
                {
                    if (property.GetMethod == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    MethodInfo setMethod = property.SetMethod;
                    if (setMethod != null && !setMethod.IsPublic)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    Type type = property.PropertyType;
                    Type entityType = GetIDbSetTypeArgument(type);

                    if (entityType == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (!type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(DbSet<>).MakeGenericType(entityType)))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    Type dbSetType = typeof(DbSet<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);

                    ConstructorInfo constructor = typeof(ProxyDbSet<>)
                        .MakeGenericType(entityType)
                        .GetConstructor(new[] 
                    { 
                        dbSetType, 
                        typeof(Func<bool, Expression, Expression>) 
                    });

                    MemberExpression property2 = Expression.Property(context, property);
                    BinaryExpression assign = Expression.Assign(property2, Expression.New(constructor, Expression.Convert(property2, dbSetType), manipulator));

                    sets.Add(assign);
                }

                Expression<Action<TContext>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<TContext>>(Expression.Block(sets), context);
                Do = lambda.Compile();
            }

            // Gets the T of IDbSetlt;T&gt;
            private static Type GetIDbSetTypeArgument(Type type)
            {
                IEnumerable<Type> interfaces = type.IsInterface ?
                    new[] { type }.Concat(type.GetInterfaces()) :
                    type.GetInterfaces();

                Type argument = (from x in interfaces
                                 where x.IsGenericType
                                 let gt = x.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
                                 where gt == typeof(IDbSet<>)
                                 select x.GetGenericArguments()[0]).SingleOrDefault();
                return argument;
            }
        }

        public readonly Func<bool, Expression, Expression> Manipulator;

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="manipulator">First parameter: true for Execute, false for CreateQuery.</param>
        /// <param name="resetSets">True to have all the DbSet&lt;TEntity&gt; and IDbSet&lt;TEntity&gt; proxified</param>
        public ProxyDbContext(Func<bool, Expression, Expression> manipulator, bool resetSets = true)
        {
            Manipulator = manipulator;

            if (resetSets)
            {
                ProxifySetsMethod.MakeGenericMethod(GetType()).Invoke(this, null);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="nameOrConnectionString"></param>
        /// <param name="manipulator">First parameter: true for Execute, false for CreateQuery.</param>
        /// <param name="resetSets">True to have all the DbSet&lt;TEntity&gt; and IDbSet&lt;TEntity&gt; proxified</param>
        public ProxyDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString, Func<bool, Expression, Expression> manipulator, bool resetSets = true)
            : base(nameOrConnectionString)
        {
            Manipulator = manipulator;

            if (resetSets)
            {
                ProxifySetsMethod.MakeGenericMethod(GetType()).Invoke(this, null);
            }
        }

        protected void ProxifySets<TContext>() where TContext : ProxyDbContext
        {
            ProxyDbContexSetter<TContext>.Do((TContext)this);
        }

        public override DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>()
        {
            return new ProxyDbSet<TEntity>(base.Set<TEntity>(), Manipulator);
        }

        public override DbSet Set(Type entityType)
        {
            DbSet set = base.Set(entityType);
            ConstructorInfo constructor = typeof(ProxyDbSetNonGeneric<>)
                .MakeGenericType(entityType)
                .GetConstructor(new[] 
                { 
                    typeof(DbSet), 
                    typeof(Func<bool, Expression, Expression>) 
                });

            return (DbSet)constructor.Invoke(new object[] { set, Manipulator });
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The DbSet, that is implemented as InternalDbSet&lt&gt; by EF.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TEntity"></typeparam>
    public class ProxyDbSetNonGeneric<TEntity> : DbSet, IQueryable<TEntity>, IEnumerable<TEntity>, IDbAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>, IQueryable, IEnumerable, IDbAsyncEnumerable where TEntity : class
    {
        protected readonly DbSet BaseDbSet;
        protected readonly IQueryable<TEntity> ProxyQueryable;

        public readonly Func<bool, Expression, Expression> Manipulator;

        protected readonly FieldInfo InternalSetField = typeof(DbSet).GetField("_internalSet", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="baseDbSet"></param>
        /// <param name="manipulator">First parameter: true for Execute, false for CreateQuery.</param>
        public ProxyDbSetNonGeneric(DbSet baseDbSet, Func<bool, Expression, Expression> manipulator)
        {
            BaseDbSet = baseDbSet;

            IQueryProvider provider = ((IQueryable)baseDbSet).Provider;
            ProxyDbProvider proxyDbProvider = new ProxyDbProvider(provider, manipulator);

            ProxyQueryable = proxyDbProvider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(((IQueryable)baseDbSet).Expression);
            Manipulator = manipulator;

            if (InternalSetField != null)
            {
                InternalSetField.SetValue(this, InternalSetField.GetValue(baseDbSet));
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="baseDbSet"></param>
        /// <param name="proxyQueryable"></param>
        /// <param name="manipulator">First parameter: true for Execute, false for CreateQuery.</param>
        public ProxyDbSetNonGeneric(DbSet baseDbSet, ProxyQueryable<TEntity> proxyQueryable, Func<bool, Expression, Expression> manipulator)
        {
            BaseDbSet = baseDbSet;

            ProxyQueryable = proxyQueryable;
            Manipulator = manipulator;

            if (InternalSetField != null)
            {
                InternalSetField.SetValue(this, InternalSetField.GetValue(baseDbSet));
            }
        }

        public override object Add(object entity)
        {
            return BaseDbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        public override IEnumerable AddRange(IEnumerable entities)
        {
            return BaseDbSet.AddRange(entities);
        }

        public override DbQuery AsNoTracking()
        {
            return new ProxyDbSetNonGeneric<TEntity>(BaseDbSet, new ProxyQueryable<TEntity>((ProxyDbProvider)ProxyQueryable.Provider, (IQueryable<TEntity>)BaseDbSet.AsNoTracking()), Manipulator);
        }

        [Obsolete]
        public override DbQuery AsStreaming()
        {
#pragma warning disable 618
            return new ProxyDbSetNonGeneric<TEntity>(BaseDbSet, new ProxyQueryable<TEntity>((ProxyDbProvider)ProxyQueryable.Provider, (IQueryable<TEntity>)BaseDbSet.AsStreaming()), Manipulator);
#pragma warning restore 618
        }

        public override object Attach(object entity)
        {
            return BaseDbSet.Attach(entity);
        }

        public override object Create(Type derivedEntityType)
        {
            return BaseDbSet.Create(derivedEntityType);
        }

        public override object Create()
        {
            return BaseDbSet.Create();
        }

        public override object Find(params object[] keyValues)
        {
            return BaseDbSet.Find(keyValues);
        }

        public override Task<object> FindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, params object[] keyValues)
        {
            return BaseDbSet.FindAsync(cancellationToken, keyValues);
        }

        public override Task<object> FindAsync(params object[] keyValues)
        {
            return BaseDbSet.FindAsync(keyValues);
        }

        public override DbQuery Include(string path)
        {
            return new ProxyDbSetNonGeneric<TEntity>(BaseDbSet, new ProxyQueryable<TEntity>((ProxyDbProvider)ProxyQueryable.Provider, (IQueryable<TEntity>)BaseDbSet.Include(path)), Manipulator);
        }

        public override IList Local
        {
            get
            {
                return BaseDbSet.Local;
            }
        }

        public override object Remove(object entity)
        {
            return BaseDbSet.Remove(entity);
        }

        public override IEnumerable RemoveRange(IEnumerable entities)
        {
            return BaseDbSet.RemoveRange(entities);
        }

        public override DbSqlQuery SqlQuery(string sql, params object[] parameters)
        {
            return BaseDbSet.SqlQuery(sql, parameters);
        }

        IEnumerator<TEntity> IEnumerable<TEntity>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ProxyQueryable.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IEnumerable)ProxyQueryable).GetEnumerator();
        }

        Type IQueryable.ElementType
        {
            get { return ProxyQueryable.ElementType; }
        }

        Expression IQueryable.Expression
        {
            get { return ProxyQueryable.Expression; }
        }

        IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider
        {
            get { return ProxyQueryable.Provider; }
        }

        IDbAsyncEnumerator<TEntity> IDbAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>.GetAsyncEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IDbAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>)ProxyQueryable).GetAsyncEnumerator();
        }

        IDbAsyncEnumerator IDbAsyncEnumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IDbAsyncEnumerable)ProxyQueryable).GetAsyncEnumerator();
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ProxyQueryable.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class ProxyDbSet<TEntity> : DbSet<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>, IEnumerable<TEntity>, IDbAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>, IQueryable, IEnumerable, IDbAsyncEnumerable where TEntity : class
    {
        protected readonly DbSet<TEntity> BaseDbSet;
        protected readonly IQueryable<TEntity> ProxyQueryable;

        public readonly Func<bool, Expression, Expression> Manipulator;

        protected readonly FieldInfo InternalSetField = typeof(DbSet<TEntity>).GetField("_internalSet", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="baseDbSet"></param>
        /// <param name="manipulator">First parameter: true for Execute, false for CreateQuery.</param>
        public ProxyDbSet(DbSet<TEntity> baseDbSet, Func<bool, Expression, Expression> manipulator)
        {
            BaseDbSet = baseDbSet;

            IQueryProvider provider = ((IQueryable)baseDbSet).Provider;
            ProxyDbProvider proxyDbProvider = new ProxyDbProvider(provider, manipulator);

            ProxyQueryable = proxyDbProvider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(((IQueryable)baseDbSet).Expression);
            Manipulator = manipulator;

            if (InternalSetField != null)
            {
                InternalSetField.SetValue(this, InternalSetField.GetValue(baseDbSet));
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="baseDbSet"></param>
        /// <param name="proxyQueryable"></param>
        /// <param name="manipulator">First parameter: true for Execute, false for CreateQuery.</param>
        public ProxyDbSet(DbSet<TEntity> baseDbSet, ProxyQueryable<TEntity> proxyQueryable, Func<bool, Expression, Expression> manipulator)
        {
            BaseDbSet = baseDbSet;

            ProxyQueryable = proxyQueryable;
            Manipulator = manipulator;

            if (InternalSetField != null)
            {
                InternalSetField.SetValue(this, InternalSetField.GetValue(baseDbSet));
            }
        }

        public override TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
        {
            return BaseDbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        public override IEnumerable<TEntity> AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
        {
            return BaseDbSet.AddRange(entities);
        }

        public override DbQuery<TEntity> AsNoTracking()
        {
            return new ProxyDbSet<TEntity>(BaseDbSet, new ProxyQueryable<TEntity>((ProxyDbProvider)ProxyQueryable.Provider, BaseDbSet.AsNoTracking()), Manipulator);
        }

        [Obsolete]
        public override DbQuery<TEntity> AsStreaming()
        {
#pragma warning disable 618
            return new ProxyDbSet<TEntity>(BaseDbSet, new ProxyQueryable<TEntity>((ProxyDbProvider)ProxyQueryable.Provider, BaseDbSet.AsStreaming()), Manipulator);
#pragma warning restore 618
        }

        public override TEntity Attach(TEntity entity)
        {
            return BaseDbSet.Attach(entity);
        }

        public override TDerivedEntity Create<TDerivedEntity>()
        {
            return BaseDbSet.Create<TDerivedEntity>();
        }

        public override TEntity Create()
        {
            return BaseDbSet.Create();
        }

        public override TEntity Find(params object[] keyValues)
        {
            return BaseDbSet.Find(keyValues);
        }

        public override Task<TEntity> FindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, params object[] keyValues)
        {
            return BaseDbSet.FindAsync(cancellationToken, keyValues);
        }

        public override Task<TEntity> FindAsync(params object[] keyValues)
        {
            return BaseDbSet.FindAsync(keyValues);
        }

        public override DbQuery<TEntity> Include(string path)
        {
            return new ProxyDbSet<TEntity>(BaseDbSet, new ProxyQueryable<TEntity>((ProxyDbProvider)ProxyQueryable.Provider, BaseDbSet.Include(path)), Manipulator);
        }

        public override ObservableCollection<TEntity> Local
        {
            get
            {
                return BaseDbSet.Local;
            }
        }

        public override TEntity Remove(TEntity entity)
        {
            return BaseDbSet.Remove(entity);
        }

        public override IEnumerable<TEntity> RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
        {
            return BaseDbSet.RemoveRange(entities);
        }

        public override DbSqlQuery<TEntity> SqlQuery(string sql, params object[] parameters)
        {
            return BaseDbSet.SqlQuery(sql, parameters);
        }

        IEnumerator<TEntity> IEnumerable<TEntity>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ProxyQueryable.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IEnumerable)ProxyQueryable).GetEnumerator();
        }

        Type IQueryable.ElementType
        {
            get { return ProxyQueryable.ElementType; }
        }

        Expression IQueryable.Expression
        {
            get { return ProxyQueryable.Expression; }
        }

        IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider
        {
            get { return ProxyQueryable.Provider; }
        }

        IDbAsyncEnumerator<TEntity> IDbAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>.GetAsyncEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IDbAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>)ProxyQueryable).GetAsyncEnumerator();
        }

        IDbAsyncEnumerator IDbAsyncEnumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IDbAsyncEnumerable)ProxyQueryable).GetAsyncEnumerator();
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ProxyQueryable.ToString();
        }

        // Note that the operator isn't virtual! If you do:
        // DbSet<Foo> foo = new ProxyDbSet<Foo>(...)
        // DbSet foo2 = (DbSet)foo;
        // Then you'll have a non-proxed DbSet!
        public static implicit operator ProxyDbSetNonGeneric<TEntity>(ProxyDbSet<TEntity> entry)
        {
            return new ProxyDbSetNonGeneric<TEntity>((DbSet)entry.BaseDbSet, entry.Manipulator);
        }
    }

    public class ProxyDbProvider : IQueryProvider, IDbAsyncQueryProvider
    {
        protected readonly IQueryProvider BaseQueryProvider;
        public readonly Func<bool, Expression, Expression> Manipulator;

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="baseQueryProvider"></param>
        /// <param name="manipulator">First parameter: true for Execute, false for CreateQuery.</param>
        public ProxyDbProvider(IQueryProvider baseQueryProvider, Func<bool, Expression, Expression> manipulator)
        {
            BaseQueryProvider = baseQueryProvider;
            Manipulator = manipulator;
        }

        public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
        {
            Expression expression2 = Manipulator != null ? Manipulator(false, expression) : expression;

            IQueryable<TElement> query = BaseQueryProvider.CreateQuery<TElement>(expression2);
            IQueryProvider provider = query.Provider;
            ProxyDbProvider proxy = provider == BaseQueryProvider ? this : new ProxyDbProvider(provider, Manipulator);

            return new ProxyQueryable<TElement>(proxy, query);
        }

        protected static readonly MethodInfo CreateQueryNonGenericToGenericMethod = typeof(ProxyDbProvider).GetMethod("CreateQueryNonGenericToGeneric", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
        {
            Expression expression2 = Manipulator != null ? Manipulator(false, expression) : expression;

            IQueryable query = BaseQueryProvider.CreateQuery(expression2);
            IQueryProvider provider = query.Provider;

            ProxyDbProvider proxy = provider == BaseQueryProvider ? this : new ProxyDbProvider(provider, Manipulator);

            Type entityType = GetIQueryableTypeArgument(query.GetType());

            if (entityType == null)
            {
                return new ProxyQueryable(proxy, query);
            }
            else
            {
                return (IQueryable)CreateQueryNonGenericToGenericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(entityType).Invoke(null, new object[] { proxy, query });
            }
        }

        protected static ProxyQueryable<TElement> CreateQueryNonGenericToGeneric<TElement>(ProxyDbProvider proxy, IQueryable<TElement> query)
        {
            return new ProxyQueryable<TElement>(proxy, query);
        }

        public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
        {
            Expression expression2 = Manipulator != null ? Manipulator(true, expression) : expression;
            return BaseQueryProvider.Execute<TResult>(expression2);
        }

        public object Execute(Expression expression)
        {
            Expression expression2 = Manipulator != null ? Manipulator(true, expression) : expression;
            return BaseQueryProvider.Execute(expression2);
        }

        // Gets the T of IQueryablelt;T&gt;
        protected static Type GetIQueryableTypeArgument(Type type)
        {
            IEnumerable<Type> interfaces = type.IsInterface ?
                new[] { type }.Concat(type.GetInterfaces()) :
                type.GetInterfaces();
            Type argument = (from x in interfaces
                             where x.IsGenericType
                             let gt = x.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
                             where gt == typeof(IQueryable<>)
                             select x.GetGenericArguments()[0]).FirstOrDefault();
            return argument;
        }

        public Task<TResult> ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var asyncQueryProvider = BaseQueryProvider as IDbAsyncQueryProvider;

            if (asyncQueryProvider == null)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }

            Expression expression2 = Manipulator != null ? Manipulator(true, expression) : expression;
            return asyncQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync<TResult>(expression2, cancellationToken);
        }

        public Task<object> ExecuteAsync(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var asyncQueryProvider = BaseQueryProvider as IDbAsyncQueryProvider;

            if (asyncQueryProvider == null)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }

            Expression expression2 = Manipulator != null ? Manipulator(true, expression) : expression;
            return asyncQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync(expression2, cancellationToken);
        }
    }

    public class ProxyQueryable : IOrderedQueryable, IQueryable, IEnumerable, IDbAsyncEnumerable
    {
        protected readonly ProxyDbProvider ProxyDbProvider;
        protected readonly IQueryable BaseQueryable;

        public ProxyQueryable(ProxyDbProvider proxyDbProvider, IQueryable baseQueryable)
        {
            ProxyDbProvider = proxyDbProvider;
            BaseQueryable = baseQueryable;
        }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return BaseQueryable.GetEnumerator();
        }

        public Type ElementType
        {
            get { return BaseQueryable.ElementType; }
        }

        public Expression Expression
        {
            get { return BaseQueryable.Expression; }
        }

        public IQueryProvider Provider
        {
            get { return ProxyDbProvider; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return BaseQueryable.ToString();
        }

        IDbAsyncEnumerator IDbAsyncEnumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator()
        {
            var asyncEnumerator = BaseQueryable as IDbAsyncEnumerable;

            if (asyncEnumerator == null)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }

            return asyncEnumerator.GetAsyncEnumerator();
        }
    }

    public class ProxyQueryable<TElement> : IOrderedQueryable<TElement>, IQueryable<TElement>, IEnumerable<TElement>, IDbAsyncEnumerable<TElement>, IOrderedQueryable, IQueryable, IEnumerable, IDbAsyncEnumerable
    {
        protected readonly ProxyDbProvider ProxyDbProvider;
        protected readonly IQueryable<TElement> BaseQueryable;

        public ProxyQueryable(ProxyDbProvider proxyDbProvider, IQueryable<TElement> baseQueryable)
        {
            ProxyDbProvider = proxyDbProvider;
            BaseQueryable = baseQueryable;
        }

        public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return BaseQueryable.GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IEnumerable)BaseQueryable).GetEnumerator();
        }

        public Type ElementType
        {
            get { return BaseQueryable.ElementType; }
        }

        public Expression Expression
        {
            get { return BaseQueryable.Expression; }
        }

        public IQueryProvider Provider
        {
            get { return ProxyDbProvider; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return BaseQueryable.ToString();
        }

        public IDbAsyncEnumerator<TElement> GetAsyncEnumerator()
        {
            var asyncEnumerator = BaseQueryable as IDbAsyncEnumerable<TElement>;

            if (asyncEnumerator == null)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }

            return asyncEnumerator.GetAsyncEnumerator();
        }

        IDbAsyncEnumerator IDbAsyncEnumerable.GetAsyncEnumerator()
        {
            var asyncEnumerator = BaseQueryable as IDbAsyncEnumerable;

            if (asyncEnumerator == null)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }

            return asyncEnumerator.GetAsyncEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

An example of a manipulator of `Expression`s (this one will transform `.Where(x => something)` to `.Where(x => something && something)`:

```
namespace My
{
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;

    public class MyExpressionManipulator : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
        {
            if (node.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(Queryable) && node.Method.Name == "Where" && node.Arguments.Count == 2)
            {
                // Transforms all the .Where(x => something) in
                // .Where(x => something && something)
                if (node.Arguments[1].NodeType == ExpressionType.Quote)
                {
                    UnaryExpression argument1 = (UnaryExpression)node.Arguments[1]; // Expression.Quote

                    if (argument1.Operand.NodeType == ExpressionType.Lambda)
                    {
                        LambdaExpression argument1lambda = (LambdaExpression)argument1.Operand;

                        // Important: at each step you'll reevalute the
                        // full expression! Try to not replace twice
                        // the expression!
                        // So if you have a query like:
                        // var res = ctx.Where(x => true).Where(x => true).Select(x => 1)
                        // the first time you'll visit
                        //  ctx.Where(x => true)
                        // and you'll obtain
                        //  ctx.Where(x => true && true)
                        // the second time you'll visit
                        //  ctx.Where(x => true && true).Where(x => true)
                        // and you want to obtain
                        //  ctx.Where(x => true && true).Where(x => true && true)
                        // and not
                        //  ctx.Where(x => (true && true) && (true && true)).Where(x => true && true)
                        if (argument1lambda.Body.NodeType != ExpressionType.AndAlso)
                        {
                            var arguments = new Expression[node.Arguments.Count];
                            node.Arguments.CopyTo(arguments, 0);

                            arguments[1] = Expression.Quote(Expression.Lambda(Expression.AndAlso(argument1lambda.Body, argument1lambda.Body), argument1lambda.Parameters));
                            MethodCallExpression node2 = Expression.Call(node.Object, node.Method, arguments);
                            node = node2;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Now... How to use it? The best way is to derive your context (in this case Model1) not from `DbContext` but from `ProxyDbContext`, like this:

```
public partial class Model1 : ProxyDbContext
{
    public Model1()
        : base("name=Model1", Manipulate)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="executing">true: the returned Expression will be executed directly, false: the returned expression will be returned as IQueryable&lt&gt.</param>
    /// <param name="expression"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static Expression Manipulate(bool executing, Expression expression)
    {
        // See the annotation about reexecuting the same visitor
        // multiple times in MyExpressionManipulator().Visit .
        // By executing the visitor only on executing == true,
        // and simply return expression; on executing == false,
        // you have the guarantee that an expression won't be
        // manipulated multiple times.
        // As written now, the expression will be manipulated
        // multiple times.
        return new MyExpressionManipulator().Visit(expression);
    }

    // Some tables
    public virtual DbSet<Parent> Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual IDbSet<Child> Child { get; set; }
```

Then it is very transparent:

```
// Where Model1: class Model1 : ProxyDbContext {}
using (var ctx = new Model1())
{
    // Your query
    var res = ctx.Parent.Where(x => x.Id > 100);
    // The query is automatically manipulated by your Manipulate method
}
```

another way to do this **without subclassing from `ProxyDbContext`**:

```
// Where Model1: class Model1 : ProxyDbContext {}
using (var ctx = new Model1())
{
    Func<Expression, Expression> manipulator = new MyExpressionManipulator().Visit;
    ctx.Parent = new ProxyDbSet<Parent>(ctx.Parent, manipulator);
    ctx.Child = new ProxyDbSet<Child>(ctx.Child, manipulator);

    // Your query
    var res = ctx.Parent.Where(x => x.Id > 100);
}
```

The `ProxyDbContext<>` replaces the `DbSet<>`/`IDbSet<>` that are present in your context with some `ProxyDbSet<>`.

In the second example this action is done explicitly, but note taht you can create a method to do it, or create a factory for your context (a static method that returns a context with the various `DbSet<>` "proxied"), or you could put the proxification in the constructor of your context (because the "original" initialization of the `DbSet<>` happens in the constructor of `DbContext`, and the body of the constructor of your context is executed after this), or you could create multiple subclasses of your context, each one that has the constructor that proxifies in a different way...

Note that the first method (subclassing `ProxyDbContext<>`) "fixes" the `Set<>`/`Set` methods that otherwise you'll have to fix yourself by copying the code of the overloads of these two methodsd from `ProxyDbContext<>`.

Comment: hmm.. creating own provider seems difficult to me. because we need to utilized this interface only (from eg. IGenericQuery and  ISampleQ). While the other suggested solution - FixMyQuery() I'm not really sure if this answer my question, since the base generic interface on the of these interfaces like IExecuteQuery same signature with these - IGenericQuery  and ISampleQ

Comment: @altyne It isn't very "long" as "in number of lines" (let's say 200 lines with a little comments)... But it is a little complex. It is "advanced" programming. I've already written two IQueryProvider for other responses, and each time it was very "try and retry".

Comment: I cannot imagine a scenario where you actually wanna go this way. A more common scenario is to simply visit your expression tree before executing the query, and manipulate it the way you want. It is also much easier to do.

Comment: @MBoros The problem is that the "converter" way can easily left you open to forgetfulness. It is difficult to check that all the queries have it.

Comment: You can wrap the original query provider with your own implmentation. Pass all method to the wrapped provider, (excpet the property that gets the provider), and override the execute method, that does your expression visiting. This is quite easy, since the IQueryProvider has only 4 methods.
BTW if you use EF, you can intercept the queries too :P

Comment: @MBoros can you show me a little bit of code on how to do it. I think for me it is very advance.

Comment: @altyne It became a little longer than I had hoped... 800 lines long. But it was interesting. See the big block of code. Note that I have done some tests, but it is "the undiscovered country".

Comment: @xanatos thanks for that code. I will try this one. The code looks promising.  However, I take different approach. I requested the other team to create overload for us Query<T>(Expression<Func<T,bool> predicate) for the meantime (hacks)

Comment: @xanatos: wow man, you are a machine :)
congrat for all this code!!

Comment: @xanatos Thanks; I am very grateful to you. This can be help others too :D